# How to resolve "only integer tensors of a single element can be converted to an index" error when creating a Dataset to fine-tune GPT2 model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, google-colaboratory

so I'm trying to fine tune gpt2 for my dataset which is just a list of tweets which I scraped

Here is my code below which is supposed to be used to fine tune the gpt2 model , I'm using the transformers library

```py
# Load the GPT2 tokenizer and model
tokenizer = GPT2Tokenizer.from_pretrained('gpt2')
model = GPT2LMHeadModel.from_pretrained('gpt2')


# Encode the training data
encoded_data = tokenizer('\n'.join(tweets), return_tensors='pt')

# Create a PyTorch dataset from the encoded data
dataset = TextDataset(encoded_data['input_ids'], encoded_data['attention_mask'],block_size = 512)

# Create a data collator for language modeling
data_collator = DataCollatorForLanguageModeling(tokenizer=tokenizer, mlm=False)

# Define the training arguments
training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir='./results',
    overwrite_output_dir=True,
    num_train_epochs=3,
    per_device_train_batch_size=16,
    save_total_limit=2,
    prediction_loss_only=True,
)

# Create a trainer for the model
trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=dataset,
    data_collator=data_collator,
)

# Fine-tune the model on the training data
trainer.train()
```

So the code throws the error whenever I run it

```
Token indices sequence length is longer than the specified maximum sequence length for this model (2081 > 1024). Running this sequence through the model will result in indexing errors
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/transformers/data/datasets/language_modeling.py:53: FutureWarning: This dataset will be removed from the library soon, preprocessing should be handled with the  Datasets library. You can have a look at this example script for pointers: https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/main/examples/pytorch/language-modeling/run_mlm.py
  warnings.warn(
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-d2c5122f870d> in <module>
      8 
      9 # Create a PyTorch dataset from the encoded data
---> 10 dataset = TextDataset(encoded_data['input_ids'], encoded_data['attention_mask'],block_size = 512)
     11 
     12 # Create a data collator for language modeling

1 frames
/usr/lib/python3.9/genericpath.py in isfile(path)
     28     """Test whether a path is a regular file"""
     29     try:
---> 30         st = os.stat(path)
     31     except (OSError, ValueError):
     32         return False

TypeError: only integer tensors of a single element can be converted to an index
```

The code is being run on `Google Colab` environment

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/75799722/610569

Answer (score 2):

This question is similar to [How to deal with stack expects each tensor to be equal size eror while fine tuning GPT-2 model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75799722/how-to-deal-with-stack-expects-each-tensor-to-be-equal-size-eror-while-fine-tuni) but it's a little different since the other questions shows model training without the usage of `Trainer` objects but this question uses it.

Additionally, there's a usage of a deprecated `TextDataset` object, thus an answer could be justifiably warranted.

---

## TL;DR

Firstly, the `TextDataset` object is deprecated. And if you want a fuzz-free approach to tune a GPT model, see https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/tree/main/examples/pytorch/language-modeling

---

## In Long

While the code for `GPT2LMHeadModel` is on

- https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/main/src/transformers/models/gpt2/modeling_gpt2.py,

the canonical example code for fine-tuning a language model is

- https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/main/examples/pytorch/language-modeling/run_clm.py

The example uses `wikitext` dataset as an example to run the CLI training, so to look into Python under the hood, we can start with:

```
from datasets import load_dataset

wikitext = load_dataset('wikitext')

wikitext
```

[out]:

```
DatasetDict({
    test: Dataset({
        features: ['text'],
        num_rows: 4358
    })
    train: Dataset({
        features: ['text'],
        num_rows: 36718
    })
    validation: Dataset({
        features: ['text'],
        num_rows: 3760
    })
})
```

If we look into the individual dataset split, e.g.

```
# The data on the 10th index.
wikitext['train'][10]
```

[out]:

```
{'text': ' The game \'s battle system , the <unk> system , is carried over directly from <unk> Chronicles . During missions , players select each unit using a top @-@ down perspective of the battlefield map : once a character is selected , the player moves the character around the battlefield in third @-@ person . A character can only act once per @-@ turn , but characters can be granted multiple turns at the expense of other characters \' turns . Each character has a field and distance of movement limited by their Action <unk> . Up to nine characters can be assigned to a single mission . During gameplay , characters will call out if something happens to them , such as their health points ( HP ) getting low or being knocked out by enemy attacks . Each character has specific " Potentials " , skills unique to each character . They are divided into " Personal Potential " , which are innate skills that remain unaltered unless otherwise dictated by the story and can either help or impede a character , and " Battle Potentials " , which are grown throughout the game and always grant <unk> to a character . To learn Battle Potentials , each character has a unique " Masters Table " , a grid @-@ based skill table that can be used to acquire and link different skills . Characters also have Special <unk> that grant them temporary <unk> on the battlefield : Kurt can activate " Direct Command " and move around the battlefield without <unk> his Action Point gauge , the character <unk> can shift into her " Valkyria Form " and become <unk> , while Imca can target multiple enemy units with her heavy weapon . \n'}
```

Given the knowledge of how the `wikitext` dataset is structured, instead of using the old `TextDataset`, to use your own custom data with the new generic `Dataset` object, it'll be simply:

```
from datasets import Dataset

texts = ["hello world", 'fizz buzz and foo bar', 'hallo welt is hello world in German', 'foo bar bar bleh sheep']

my_dataset = Dataset.from_dict({'text': texts})

my_dataset[2]
```

[out]:

```
{'text': 'hallo welt is hello world in German'}
```

Now we have the same structure to the `Dataset` object as per `wikitext`. Then to fine-tune the model, we can simply reuse the rest of the code from https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/main/examples/pytorch/language-modeling/run_clm.py

Here's a minimal working example:

```py
from itertools import chain

from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForCausalLM
from transformers import default_data_collator
from transformers import Trainer

from datasets import Dataset

import evaluate

# Load the GPT2 tokenizer and model
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('gpt2')
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained('gpt2')

embedding_size = model.get_input_embeddings().weight.shape[0]
if len(tokenizer) > embedding_size:
    model.resize_token_embeddings(len(tokenizer))

MAX_LENGTH = tokenizer.model_max_length



# From https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/main/examples/pytorch/language-modeling/run_clm.py#L489 
# Main data processing function that will concatenate all texts from our dataset and generate chunks of block_size.
def group_texts(examples, block_size=MAX_LENGTH):
    # Concatenate all texts.
    concatenated_examples = {k: list(chain(*examples[k])) for k in examples.keys()}
    total_length = len(concatenated_examples[list(examples.keys())[0]])
    # We drop the small remainder, we could add padding if the model supported it instead of this drop, you can
    # customize this part to your needs.
    if total_length >= block_size:
        total_length = (total_length // block_size) * block_size
    # Split by chunks of max_len.
    result = {
        k: [t[i : i + block_size] for i in range(0, total_length, block_size)]
        for k, t in concatenated_examples.items()
    }
    result["labels"] = result["input_ids"].copy()
    return result

# Training data.
texts = ["hello world", 'fizz buzz and foo bar', 'hallo welt is hello world in German', 'foo bar bar bleh sheep']
raw_datasets = Dataset.from_dict({'text': texts})

tokenized_datasets = raw_datasets.map(
    lambda x: tokenizer(x['text']),
    batched=True,
)

train_dataset = tokenized_datasets.map(
    group_texts,
    batched=True,
)

# Validation data.
eval_texts = ["hello world blah blah bad romance, ra ra fizz buzz"]

eval_dataset = Dataset.from_dict({'text': texts}).map(
    lambda x: tokenizer(x['text']),
    batched=True,
).map(
    group_texts,
    batched=True,
)


metric = evaluate.load("accuracy")

def compute_metrics(eval_preds):
    preds, labels = eval_preds
    # preds have the same shape as the labels, after the argmax(-1) has been calculated
    # by preprocess_logits_for_metrics but we need to shift the labels
    labels = labels[:, 1:].reshape(-1)
    preds = preds[:, :-1].reshape(-1)
    return metric.compute(predictions=preds, references=labels)


# Initialize our Trainer
trainer = Trainer(
  model=model,
  train_dataset=train_dataset,
  eval_dataset=eval_dataset,
  tokenizer=tokenizer,
  
  data_collator=default_data_collator,
  compute_metrics=compute_metrics
)

trainer.train()
```

But do take a close look at the code on https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/main/examples/pytorch/language-modeling/run_clm.py to best understand what each part of the code is doing and if you want no-frills fine-tuning, use the CLI.